# Experimentation Sandbox

Tags: discussion, support, markdown, formatting

This is a sandbox post for experimenting with SE features, similar to the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Test test test test

Comment: ＠MichaelMrozek​

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: [help] - [tour] - [chat].

Answer (score 7):

```
make unix | more > /usr/friendly
```

should give this friendly message:

> `make: *** No rule to make target 'unix'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 4):

Comment: [­](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

Will this put everything below this in a `<code>` tag on the mobile site (and maybe also on the desktop site on some computers / browsers)?

I think it did.  (I deleted it because it messed up the sandbox, see edit history, Kusalananda)

Answer (score 1):

`date; cd; touch; strip; finger; mount; fsck; more; yes; unmount; sleep`

```
date; cd; touch; strip; finger; mount; fsck; more; yes; unmount; sleep
```

```
date; cd; touch; strip; finger; mount; fsck; more; yes; unmount; sleep
```

```
date; cd; touch; strip; finger; mount; fsck; more; yes; unmount; sleep
```

Dodge this:

> `date; cd; touch; strip; finger; mount; fsck; more; yes; unmount; sleep`

and that:

> date; cd; touch; strip; finger; mount; fsck; more; yes; unmount; sleep

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=foo

Comment: Testing testing

Comment: @Gilles 7654321

Comment: @Gilles wibble [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/151)

Comment: You misspelled `umount`.

Answer (score 1):

Code block formatting test.

```
code goes
here
```

Now this:

```
more 
here
```

---

From problematic answer:

for example:

```
ip,time,name,_random
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,65536
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,42
```

or

```
ip,time,name,_seq
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,1
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,2
```

But, you can not use too many numbers for the same tag. Influx by default sets max-tag-per-value to 100000.

Answer (score 0):

When I was a kid, sand never stayed in the sandbox <strike>for very long</strike>.

Answer (score 0):

[100](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#stream/user/16600082639541088206/state/com.google/reading-list)
[200](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackapplet/)
[300](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackapplet/)

[main] rocks like a...

Comment: [meta-tag:support]

Comment: On [main], you are expected to write proper English (as advertised on [english.se]), but here on [metase] it's more important to have freehand circles, so please [edit] your post, otherwise I'll have to flag you (see the [FAQ#flagging]). If you're unsure how to use your keyboard, [su] is the right place to ask. There's no Q&A site about unicorns yet, but you can suggest one on [area51.se].

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why [question:646] or [answer:646#683] are not hyperlinkified.

An other test: link to this anwser (failed)

Links to the question: [Experimentation Sandbox](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/646/experimentation-sandbox) or [this](/q/646). Ok, these ones work.

Comment: There is a [magic link system for comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments), but it only works in comments and doesn't include question/answers. If you know the ID you can just link to unix.stackexchange.com/q/646

Comment: I knew about those. The ones I wish for would display the current title of the question (plus the name of the author for answers), and update with future edits.

Comment: A link to a question will get turned into the title of the question; I'm not sure about answers. They don't update though, it would be too much load on the servers to try and keep track of all that

Comment: Testing answers links as `[text](#726)`: here is a link to [my own answer](#726) (maybe).

Comment: Argh, failed :/

Comment: Ah, apparently not in comments. [Example answer](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646/experimentation-sandbox/727#727) ([source](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/43ac5802-7726-4797-b9c6-9e7eb056e3ed/view-source))

Comment: link to this question: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646/experimentation-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

> `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18659/running-proprietary-software-on-linux-safely`

[Running proprietary software on Linux safely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18659/running-proprietary-software-on-linux-safely)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, `a` and `b` separated by 5 spaces gives `a     b`.

Gee, bug? (Same with any number of spaces)

Comment: `a­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ b`

Answer (score 0):

**are these words bold?**

Comment: Yes, they are...

Answer (score 0):

quoting multiple lines

> ```
> line1
> line2
> line3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Testing embedded HTML (after the switch to CommonMark; because of https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/593519/3):

Text

---

**Bold text**

---

Text `code` text

```
some code

more code

more code

more code  



more code

more code

more code
```

---

**Bold text**

---

> **Bold quote `code` text `code` text `code` text `code` text**

---

**Bold text**

---

Text `code` text `code` text `code` text `code` text

```
  code   

  code   

  code
```

Text

Answer (score 0):

table test

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Answer (score 0):

multi-paragraph quoting test

> Bash is the shell, or command language interpreter, for the GNU operating system. The name is an acronym for the ‘Bourne-Again SHell’, a pun on Stephen Bourne, the author of the direct ancestor of the current Unix shell sh, which appeared in the Seventh Edition Bell Labs Research version of Unix.
>
> Bash is largely compatible with sh and incorporates useful features from the Korn shell ksh and the C shell csh. It is intended to be a conformant implementation of the IEEE POSIX Shell and Tools portion of the IEEE POSIX specification (IEEE Standard 1003.1). It offers functional improvements over sh for both interactive and programming use.
>
> While the GNU operating system provides other shells, including a version of csh, Bash is the default shell. Like other GNU software, Bash is quite portable. It currently runs on nearly every version of Unix and a few other operating systems - independently-supported ports exist for MS-DOS, OS/2, and Windows platforms.

Answer (score -1):

edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment 
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment
edit comment